# android block login after X failed attempts

Tags: java, android, authentication

I have an android application with login
 I'm trying to block login for x minutes after y failed attempts. 
 if user try more than y times I want to compare  with the system time and after x minute user can login how can I achieve am new to android please help me

```
lgn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        uname = user.getText().toString();
        pass = passwrd.getText().toString();

        if (isConnectingToInternet()) {
            if ((passwrd.equals() == "username") || (user.equlas() == "password")) {
                Toast ->success
            }
            if(count >=4){
                // this part i dont know how to 
                //i want to block 30 minute if user tried x attemts, 
                lgnbutton->disble
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what you tried so far?

Comment: `btnLogin.setEnabled(false);` so simple.

Comment: @IntelliJ Amiya  i dont know how can i comapre with system time ,

Comment: @https://stackoverflow.com/users/7229971/kuldip-patel this is i know this is the final step ,

Comment: use countdowntimer.

Comment: @https://stackoverflow.com/users/3395198/intellij-amiya if you dont mind  can you give code for countdowntimer, i am new in android

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/3395198/intellij-amiya  if i use couter times when i close the application counter time will stop

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using system's time to calculate x minutes, you can use android's CountDownTimer class.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html

After y failed attempts, you can disable the button with `btn.setEnabled(false)` and after the counter finishes, you can enable the button with `btn.setEnabled(true)`.

You can also use a method of CountDownTimer class (`onTick`) if you wan to display the time left for the button to get enabled again.
`onTick` will be called after every interval of time that you mention as the argument in `CountDownTimer()`.

For eg.,

```
new CountDownTimer(<total_time>, <interval>) {

     public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
         //update time left
     }

     public void onFinish() {
         //enable button
     }
  }.start();
```

Comment: if i use conter timer, when i exit the application coutertimer will also stop

Comment: If you want to cancel timer, you can call cancel() method of the same class in onDestroy() of the activity.
For eg, timer=new CountDownTimer(){...}

timer.cancel()

Comment: i dont want to cancel, when i close the application it will atomatically stop,

Comment: if i set 30 minute , if i close the applciation after 5 minut and reopen couter timer will restert , so no use, i want to compre with system time

Comment: If you don't want a timer to be stopped after exiting the app, you can maintain the time left in shared preferences and when the app restarts, you can fetch remaining time from preferences and can restart the timer with that time.
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html

However, this will not work if user clears data of the app

Comment: Try with shared preferences as i mentioned, that will work.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/7482051/sumeet-rukeja will u share the code ,i dont know how to implement please

Comment: Checkout my new answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.CountDownTimer;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Button;

import java.io.IOException;

public class LogInActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button logInButton;
    private SharedPreferences prefs;
    private long timeLeft;
    private CountDownTimer timer;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_log_in);

        initTasks();

        checkTimer();
    }

    private void initTasks() {
        logInButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt);

        prefs = getSharedPreferences("file", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    }

    private void checkTimer() {
        if (prefs.contains("time"))
            setTimer();
        else {
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
            editor.putLong("time", -1L);
            editor.apply();
        }
    }

    private void setTimer() {
        timeLeft = prefs.getLong("time", -1L);
        if (timeLeft != -1L)
            startTimer(timeLeft);
        else
            logInButton.setEnabled(true);

    }

    private void startTimer(long time) {
        logInButton.setEnabled(false);
        timer = new CountDownTimer(time, 1000) {

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                logInButton.setEnabled(true);
                saveToPref(-1L);
            }

            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                //update UI, if required
                timeLeft = millisUntilFinished;
                saveToPref(timeLeft);
            }
        };
    }

    private void saveToPref(long timeLeft){
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
        editor.putLong("time", timeLeft);
        editor.apply();
    }

}
```

`call startTimer(<your_time>)` when all attempts fail. `<your_time>` is the time for which you want your button to remain disabled. It is in milliseconds.

I have not tested the code, hence issues may occur. This is the basic idea to fulfil your requirement.

Comment: thankyou for your response , i tried i failed to implement i will share the please help me to find the error  https://drive.google.com/file/d/1fCfvk-pfP6b9jscsnPYv5p892DaHJiLW/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Replace "final Button b1 = view.findViewById(R.id.button);" with "b1 = view.findViewById(R.id.button);". You are accessing global variable in "b1.setEnabled()" which is null as you have used local variable. Avoid using local variable, in this case.

Comment: There is one more error in logic implementation. 

You are calling checkTimer() on button click. It should be called after initTasks(). 

Use startTimer() when all the attempts fail, to disable the button and start the timer as i mentioned in answer.

Comment: where did call the button click?

Comment: Perform login functionality on button click. Maintain a counter to calculate number of failed attempts. If number exceeds the required limit, call startTimer().

Comment: To avoid NullPointerException, replace "final Button b1 = view.findViewById(R.id.button);" with "b1 = view.findViewById(R.id.button);".

To implement correct logic, call checkTimer() in onCreate() and increment the counter on button click. Call startTimer() from button click itself if counter limit exceeds.

That's all.

Answer (score 0):

Time counter works only when application is running. In this case i will count time in harder way. Firstly get current time in milliseconds write them in to the shared preferences and when application starts again take the written millisecond from preferences and count the interval which is left to countdown. My offer will be:

```
        // get saved time if it exist. Do it on app start or activity create
        Long defaultTime = null;
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
        Long writtenTime = null;
        try {
            writtenTime = sharedPreferences.getLong("timer", defaultTime);
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {}

        // DO THIS ONLY WHEN BUTTON IS DISABLED
        // count how much time left for countdown
        Long current = Calendar.getInstance().getTime().getTime();
        long interval = (writtenTime == null)? 30000L : current - writtenTime;

        // save new current time
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.putLong("timer", current);
        editor.apply();

        // countdown and enable button on finish
        new CountDownTimer(current+interval, interval) {
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {}

            public void onFinish() {
                btn.setEnabled(true);
            }
        }.start();
```

Comment: Thankyou for your responce i tried it shows null pointer exception on defaultTime  and  writtenTime .. i added my code please help me  https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ueu_im5MUrxLAv47GPISCqrxmzbEtoif/view?usp=sharing